# How to install pycurl on Apple M1 Silicon using pip v23.1+

Tags: python, pip, apple-m1, pycurl

Installing `pycurl` on computers with Apple M1 chips has always been a struggle. I have been using this command to install `pycurl` with OpenSSLv3 using `pip`:

```
brew update && brew install openssl
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
pip uninstall pycurl
pip install --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

But in pip v23.1+ ([see here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v23-1)), the `--install-option` has been removed and I can't figure out how to create an equivalent command.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `--install-option` was removed is that the `setup.py install` mode of installing packages has been deprecated and subsequently removed. So there is no way to tell pip to pass something to `setup.py`, as it is no longer being called, see also [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/passing-command-line-arguments-to-pip-install-after-install-options-deprecation/22981/5).

I suggest you download the pycurl sources and then manually call

```
 python setup.py --with-openssl install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed  --config-setting="--build-option=--with-openssl" pycurl
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation. You also could have a look at [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)